# Wordpress links broken when moved directory

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

My situation is as follows:

Root directory: /index.php (splash page)

Subdirectory: /2015/index.php (wordpress installation with index.php)

When I click on any links on the homepage for the 2015 Wordpress installation it opens the index.php from the root instead of the index.php (splash page) inside the subdirectory, thus none of my links are working.

Both the root and 2015 folders have a Wordpress .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Try to update the permalinks.

Comment: did you update the home and site urls in the settings?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your permalinks on both installs.

Then check `RewriteBase` in .htaccess

root install should be set to `RewriteBase /`

2015 install should be set to `RewriteBase /2015/`

If those are correct, make sure your links on the root are directing to the 2015 directory.

Answer (score 0):

before generating permalinks you need to change settings in the DB option table,

You need to change `siteurl` and `home` rows in `option`
otherwise you can also set these in the `config.php`:

```
 define('WP_HOME','http://ex.com/2015');
 define('WP_SITEURL','http://ex.com/2015');
```